# Improve the LINQ query returning indexes of items meeting a certain condition

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have this LINQ query which returns the indexes of all the items in an array whose time value (which is a `double`) meets a certain condition as in the below query.

```
var sonicIndices = completeLog.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
            .Where(x => Math.Abs(x.Item.time - nullValue) > 0.001)
            .Select(item => item.Index).ToArray();
```

I am pretty sure that this can be improved but how? I am stumped. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for an old-fashioned for loop

Comment: @DaveBish: Yeah, you may be right. But I want to improve my expertise in LINQ (Which is very low right now) that's why I asked.

Comment: @Aamir: Why do you think that this can be improved? That looks pretty straight-forward.

Comment: It basically looks fine to me as-is.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: umm... Just because this looks gross / convoluted :) So you want to say that this can't be improved?

Comment: @Aamir: No.  Actually it's rather obvious what it's doing. And a for loop wouldn't be more efficient and easier to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with that, in what way does it need to be better?
If you want a reusable method for this *kind* of thing, see: [Getting a collection of index values using a LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237377/getting-a-collection-of-index-values-using-a-linq-query)

Answer (score 3):

Not an improvement, but just another way to do the same thing:

```
var sonicIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, completeLog.Length)
                   .Where(i => Math.Abs(completeLog[i].time - nullValue) > 0.001)
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Nifty - avoiding the anon object creation.  +1