# Getting indexes of all matching items

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get the index of all items in an enumerable that match a given condition.  Is there a cleaner way than this?

```
var indexes = list.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index }).Where(o => Condition(o.Item)).Select(o => o.Index);
```

Comment: What it the generic type of the IEnumerable?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237377/getting-a-collection-of-index-values-using-a-linq-query

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using standard LINQ to Object methods - no, there's not. You only can improve readability by splitting your query into couple lines:

```
var indexes = list.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
                  .Where(o => Condition(o.Item))
                  .Select(o => o.Index);
```

However, you can write an Extension Method for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IndexesWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int index=0;
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
        {
            yield return index;
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing as I've already got a rather extensive library of extensions, I like this solution.